# How to get pixel value from ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, pixel

Is there anyways to get the pixel value from `ImageView` after the click the `button` ? I have done the digging and searching but most of the solution are using the method `imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()`.

But what I really want is get the pixel value after click on the `button`. Any recommendation ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
private Bitmap bmp;
private int[][] rgbValues;

    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.four_colors);

    //define the array size
    rgbValues = new int[bmp.getWidth()][bmp.getHeight()];

    for(int i=0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            rgbValues[i][j] = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
        }
    }
```

For full code go to this [link](http://www.41post.com/3719/programming/android-how-to-return-rgb-values-from-an-image-file).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap .getPixel(x,y);
```